# I am not able to rectify errors in this C code which is accepting user input for filling a 2d array using scanf

Tags: c, arrays, multidimensional-array

My try

```
int *nb=(int *)malloc(ntc*sizeof(int));// no of bus
int barr[ntc][ntc];// bus route array
int *nc=(int *)malloc(ntc*sizeof(int));// no of city
int carr[ntc][ntc];// city array
scanf("%d",&ntc); // input -> test case
for(i=0;i<ntc;i++)
{
    scanf("%d",&(nb[i])); // input -> no of bus

    p=2*nb[i];
    for(k = 0; k < p; k++)
    {
        scanf("%d", &(barr[i][k])); // input -> bus route array
    }

    scanf("%d", &nc[i]); // input -> no of city for which bus passing by count is to be determined 

    q=nc[i];
    for(j = 0; j < q; j++)
    {
        scanf("%d", &(carr[i][j])); // input -> city array 
    }
}
```

I am accepting input for various test cases. For test case#1 I am taking input of nb,barr,nc,carr arrays. This continues for **ntc** no of test cases. Below i have written the input statement of the problem

> The first line contains the number of test cases (T), after which T
>   cases follow each separated from the next with a blank line. For each
>   test case,  The first line contains the number of GBuses.(N)  Second
>   line contains the cities covered by them in the form  a1 b1 a2 b2 a3
>   b3...an bn  where GBus1 covers cities numbered from a1 to b1, GBus2
>   covers cities numbered from a2 to b2, GBus3 covers cities numbered
>   from a3 to b3, upto N GBuses.  Next line contains the number of cities
>   for which GBus count needs to be determined (P).  The below P lines
>   contain different city numbers.

Suppose now input is

```
2
4
15 25 30 35 45 50 10 20
2
15
25

10
10 15 5 12 40 55 1 10 25 35 45 50 20 28 27 35 15 40 4 5
3
5
10
27
```

Now when i am printing the values just for a sanity check what i am getting is very strange.

```
printf("no of test case %d\n",ntc);
for(i=0;i<ntc;i++)
{
    printf("Case #%d\n",i+1);
    printf("no of bus %d\n",nb[i]);

    p=2*nb[i];
    printf("bus route array");  
    for(j=0;j<p;j++)
    {
        printf(" %d ",barr[i][j]);
    }

    printf("\nno of city for which bus passing by count is to be determined %d \n",nc[i]);

    q=nc[i];
    printf("city array");
    for(k=0;k<q;k++)
    {
        printf(" %d ",carr[i][k]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}

no of test case 2
Case #1
no of bus 4
bus route array 10  15  5  12  40  55  1  10 
no of city for which bus passing by count is to be determined 2 
city array 5  10 
Case #2
no of bus 10
bus route array 10  15  5  12  40  55  1  10  25  35  45  50  20  28  27  35  15  40  4  5 
no of city for which bus passing by count is to be determined 3 
city array 5  10  27
```

The output for Case #1 bus route should be 15 25 30 35 45 50 10 20 and not 10 15 5 12 40 55 1 10 and for city route it should be 15 25 not 5 10

Comment: Perhaps indentation of the code and check the return values from `scanf`

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce it https://ideone.com/CvQzOb

Comment: Problem is likely where you allocate your city and buss arrays. You're not showing that though.

Comment: I have edited the code and added the array allocation

Comment: @user7 I have added the array allocation in my code can you please point out the errors.

Comment: Please explain what is strange, don't make readers guess. This is relevant, because the way you think is always important for debugging. Can you add the results of your own debugging attempts? For hints, refer to https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/ Another good technique for solving any kind of problem is described here https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/21/find-a-simpler-problem/ If you at first feel these texts are somewhat cynical please go on reading and seriously try to act as described. This is what experienced programmers do almost always when facing a problem.

Comment: @Yunnosch the output for Case #1 bus route should be 15 25 30 35 45 50 10 20 and not 10 15 5 12 40 55 1 10 and for city route it should be 15 25 not 5 10

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
int *nb=(int *)malloc(ntc*sizeof(int)); // what is ntc?
int barr[ntc][ntc];                     // what is ntc?
int *nc=(int *)malloc(ntc*sizeof(int)); // what is ntc?
int carr[ntc][ntc];                     // what is ntc?
scanf("%d",&ntc); // input -> test case // oh
```

C cannot see into the future. It is not possible to allocate an array and determine its size later. You need to read `ntc` first, then use it.

You also need to enable your compiler warnings **and make sure all your programs build warning-free**. This error can be easily caught by the compiler.

As a side note, automatic [variable-length arrays](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array) in C are dangerous since they can easily cause your program to overstep its stack size limit. Avoid them. Allocate all arrays of unknown size dynamically.

Comment: Thanks its working now and coming to your suggestions of compiler warning, gcc did not gave me any warnings otherwise I would have caught this error

Comment: @adityajain you need to enable warnings. For gcc try using `-Wall`.